# Start Sonnar from a node in jenkins

Tags: plugins, jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I wonder how to start Sonnar from a node. I have the following restrictions:

1. Only the machine it is installed on the jenkins has access to sonar
2. The build machine has no access to Sonar

I have the following settings:

1. Upon build I use post-build (copy files back to the job's workspace on the master node) and the target files are copied to the master, with the same jenkins project name but another directory.
2. I use the - Restrict where this project can be run with the name of the node (slave) which realize the build

Comments: I tried to use the Flexible publish with the execution node option as master and the Sonar, but I believe that the the restriction option must be canceling it.

My architecture is something like this:

> build machine <----(Running Build)---------Jenkins Machine
>
> build machine ----(copying files to the master)-------> Jenkins
>   Machine
>
> Jenkins Machine <---> Sonar

Answer (score 0):

One simple option would be to have a downstream job, where the workspace can be the area where your project code is available and you can restrict it to run in the master and in the build config you can invoke sonar analysis

Answer (score 0):

ok would be a way but there is a problem with that. When I use the " copy files back to the job 's workspace on the master node" project name would have to be the same as the downstream job . However , I can not create two jobs with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

questions resolve!

build machine ----(copying files to the master)-------> Jenkins Machine ---(clone workspace)---->sonar job